# Aplicar efeito de imutabilidade nos objetos de uma classe JavaScript ECMA6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Para exemplificar, tenho a seguinte classe:

```
class LavarCarro {
    constructor(cor, placa, data_entrada) {
        this._cor = cor;
        this._placa = placa;
        this._data_entrada = data_entrada;

        Object.freeze(this); // congela a instância do objeto
    }

    get cor() {
        return this._cor;
    }

    get placa() {
        return this._placa;
    }

    get dataEntrada() {
        return this._data_entrada;
    }
}
```

Para impedir que propriedades existentes, ou sua inumerabilidade, configurabilidade, ou capacidade de escrita sejam alteradas, ou seja,  transformar a essência do objeto efetivamente imutável, como todos sabem, existe o método `freeze()`.

Mas, infelizmente, conforme o exemplo a seguir mostra que  valores do tipo objeto, em um objeto congelado, podem ser alterados (*freeze* é raso).

```
var data = new LavarCarro('Preto', 'ABC1234', new Date());
console.log(data.dataEntrada);
//Mon Jul 10 2017 08:45:56 GMT-0300 (-03) - Resultado do console
data.dataEntrada.setDate(11);
console.log(data.dataEntrada);
//Tue Jul 11 2017 08:45:56 GMT-0300 (-03) - Resultado do console
```

Como posso tratar essa exceção e tonar o objeto `Date()` contido no atributo `data_entrada` imutável usando ECMA6?

Obs.: O objetivo é que as propriedades da classe `LavarCarro` sejam somente para leitura. No entanto, a linguagem JavaScript - até a atual data - não nos permite usar modificadores de acesso. Então, utilizo a convenção *underline* ( _ ) nos atributos das propriedades da classe para indicar que não podem ser modificadas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A documentação do método [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) diz, entre outras coisas, que (ênfase adicionada):

> Observe que valores que são **objetos** *ainda* podem ser modificados, a
>   menos que eles **também** sejam congelados.

---

### Como tornar um objeto imutável

Para fazer um objeto `obj` completamente imutável, é necessário congelar cada objeto presente em `obj`. Segue exemplo de código que faz isso, presente na MDN:

```js
obj1 = {
  internal: {}
};

Object.freeze(obj1);

// Objeto foi congelado mas o valor do tipo objeto ainda pode ser alterado
obj1.internal.a = 'aValue';

console.log(obj1.internal.a); // 'aValue'

// Para fazer um obj completamente imutável, congele cada objeto em obj.
// Para fazer isso, nós usamos essa função.
function deepFreeze(obj) {

  // Recuperar os nomes de propriedade definidos em obj
  var propNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);

  // Congelar as propriedades antes de congelar-se
  propNames.forEach(function(name) {
    var prop = obj[name];

    // Congele prop se for um objeto
    if (typeof prop == 'object' && prop !== null) {
      deepFreeze(prop);
    }
  });

  // Congele-se (não faz nada se já estiver congelado)
  return Object.freeze(obj);
}

obj2 = {
  internal: {}
};

deepFreeze(obj2);
obj2.internal.a = 'anotherValue';
console.log(obj2.internal.a); // undefined
```

---

### Posso tornar `Date` imutável?

Complementando a resposta, acredito que o seu problema seja em congelar um JavaScript `Date`.

Chamar `Object.freeze()` em um `Date` **não** irá prevenir mudanças à essa data. Isso ocorre pelo fato de `Date` não utilizar uma propriedade objeto para armazenar o seu valor interno. Ao invés disso, `Date` utiliza [`[[DateValue]]` *internal slot*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date-constructor). [*Internal slots*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots) não são propriedades (ênfase adicionada):

> Os *internal slots* correspondem ao estado interno que está associado à
>   objetos e usado por vários algoritmos de especificação ECMAScript. Os internal
>   slots **não são** propriedades do objeto...

Portanto, congelar o objeto ou valores que são objetos não têm nenhum efeito sobre a capacidade de modificar o *internal slot* `[[DateValue]]`. Logo, você não pode tornar `Date` imutável.

### Mas não tem jeito mesmo?

Você pode *quase totalmente* congelar `Date`, apesar de não ser 100% à prova de modificações e, consequentemente, não ser inteiramente imutável: substitua todos os métodos modificadores por funções sem operação (ou funções que lançam um erro) e então congele `Date`. Exemplo:

```js
"use strict";

function semoperacao() {
}

function congelaData(data) {
  todosNomes(data).forEach(nome => {
    if (nome.startsWith("set") && typeof data[nome] === "function") {
      data[nome] = semoperacao;
    }
  });
  Object.freeze(data);
  return data;
}

function todosNomes(obj) {
  var nomes = Object.create(null);
  var thisObj;
  
  for (thisObj = obj; thisObj; thisObj = Object.getPrototypeOf(thisObj)) {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(thisObj).forEach(nome => {
      nomes[nome] = 1;
    });
  }
  return Object.keys(nomes);
}

let data = new Date();
congelaData(data);
console.log("Data antes de congelar: " + data);
data.setTime(0);
console.log("Data depois de congelar e tentar modificar: " + data);
```

Não funciona 100% porque nada impede de alguém fazer o seguinte:

```
Date.prototype.setTime.call(d, 0)
```

Créditos para T.J. Crowder [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34907365/3551913).

Comment: Agradeço a resposta. Sobre a parte de congelar cada objeto eu já tinha conhecimento e usar o `freeze()` no `Date` vi na pratica que não funciona. A pergunta foi justamente para tentar encontrar experiências de outras pessoas sobre o mesmo assunto. Como se fosse uma esperança em busca de uma outra alternativa. Sobre as informações do `Date` imutável foram de grande ajuda e agregou conhecimento. Obrigado.

Comment: @DjalmaManfrin você até pode congelar `Date` *parcialmente*, substituindo todos os seus métodos modificadores por funções sem operação e então congelá-lo. Parcialmente pois ainda há maneiras de modificar a data. Caso queira posso complementar a resposta com essa maneira.

Comment: você está se referindo a utilizar os métodos `getter` para evitar que o atributo seja atributo valor? Exemplo: `get dataEntrada(){}`. Todo conhecimento é válido, Se puder mudar agradeço.

Comment: @DjalmaManfrin atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Interessante essa última alteração que acrescentou. Vou dar uma olhada com calma e realizar alguns testes.

Answer (score 1):

Estava lendo sobre programação defensiva e acredito ter encontrado uma alternativa para o problema do `date` ser mutável.

Para impedir que valores do tipo objeto, em um objeto congelado pelo `freeze()` sejam alterados, como por exemplo da pergunta, posso aplicar as seguintes alterações:

Toda vez que eu precisar retornar uma data ao sistema, ao invés de passar a referência do atributo da `data_entrada` do objeto, posso passar uma nova referência do objeto `Date`

```
get dataEntrada() {
    return new Date(this._data_entrada.getTime());
}
```

Ao passar uma nova instância de `Date` para o sistema, o sistema irá trabalhar um outro objeto com o mesmo valor de `this._data_entrada`. Assim, caso alguém tente alterar a data, apenas irá alterar uma cópia e não a data do objeto.

Agora se eu aplicar o teste para alterar a data do objeto, isso não irá ocorrer.

```
var data = new LavarCarro('Preto', 'ABC1234', new Date());
console.log(data.dataEntrada);
//Mon Jul 10 2017 08:45:56 GMT-0300 (-03) - Resultado do console
data.dataEntrada.setDate(11);
console.log(data.dataEntrada);
//Tue Jul 10 2017 08:45:56 GMT-0300 (-03) - Resultado do console
```

Mas se eu criar uma referência da data e passar para o construtor do objeto `class LavarCarro {}` e tentar alterar a data, conforme exemplo a seguir a data continuará a ser editada.

```
var hoje = new Date();
var data = new LavarCarro('Preto', 'ABC1234', hoje);
console.log(data.dataEntrada);
//Mon Jul 10 2017 08:45:56 GMT-0300 (-03) - Resultado do console
hoje.setDate(11);
console.log(data.dataEntrada);
//Tue Jul 11 2017 08:45:56 GMT-0300 (-03) - Resultado do console
```

Para resolver e finalizar o problema, ao receber a data no construtor, crio uma nova referência da data recebida. Dessa forma, agora eu não estou mais guardando a referência de `var hoje`, mas sim criando uma nova referência, confirme exemplo a seguir:

```
constructor(cor, placa, data_entrada) {
    this._cor = cor;
    this._placa = placa;
    this._data_entrada = new Date(data_entrada.getTime());

    Object.freeze(this); // congela a instância do objeto
}
```

Por fim, aplicando estas alterações consigo evitar o problema de atributos do tipo objeto `Date`. Eu acredito que dessa forma há contra indicações, sendo este o motivo da postagem. Quem puder comentar e me ajudar a analisar se esse conceito continua imutável agradeço desde já.